# Who made the T-Virus of Resident evil, Dr. James Marcus or Dr. Charles Ashford?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil, resident-evil-apocalypse, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

There are some contradictory things in **"Resident Evil: The Final Chapter"** that don't match the previous series:

- In **"RE: Apocalypse"**- we saw that the **T-Virus** was originated by a Level 6 Umbrella researcher Dr. Charles Ashford in order to heal his daughter Angela from some kind of disease that prevented her from walking.

*On the other hand:*

- In **"RE: Final Chapter"** the *T-Virus* was originated by Dr. James Marcus the owner of Umbrella in order to heal his daughter Alicia, who was suffering from progeria.

So, who made the T-Virus of Resident evil, Dr. James Marcus or Dr. Charles Ashford?

Comment: I would separate this into two questions.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I thought about that, but I preferred that the second could be a sub-question, thanks :)

Comment: @AhmedSuror it's better to ask them separately. I have removed second question already, feel free to ask it in different question.

Comment: Good, was going to ask the same Q. This is actually a major inconsistency in the film series.

Answer (score 5):

## Dr. Charles Ashford

The transcript for when Angela tells Alice of her father making the T-virus and anti-virus make it very clear that Ashford created it and then the Umbrella corporation took it from him.

> Angela: My daddy. **My daddy made it for me.** He's sick. And someday, I'll get sick too. He just wanted to stop that. When I was little I had to walk on crutches. They said I'd never get better, just worse. **He found a way to make me stronger.**
>   Alice: The T-virus.
>   Angela: **Then they took the invention away from him.**
>   <sub>Resident Evil, Apocalypse</sub>

Whereas, in The Final Chapter the transcript tells us that James merely just discovers it, i.e. takes it from Ashford.

> Marcus was driven to save her. But the odds seemed impossible. And **even as he worked desperately to create a cure**, the young girl's father would record his daughter, her voice, her likeness, saving her for posterity. But then a breakthrough came. **Marcus discovered the T-Virus.**
>   <sub>Resident Evil, The Final Chapter</sub>

Answer (score -3):

I had the same thought what on earth are they doing! completely ripping there own timeline apart. XD

[Dr. Ashford](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Ashford) was responsible for the creation of the **T-virus**, which could revive dead or dying cells, and although he created it for medical purposes, **Umbrella took away the virus.**

**BUT interestingly:**
**Dr. James Marcus** is an Umbrella scientist took credibility for creating the T-virus, which could revive dead cells while the real person who created it was [**Charles Ashford**](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/James_Marcus_(Anderson)).

But the last film made you think it was **James.**

But us gaming fans know that the real **Dr. James Marcus** was an American **virologist** who pioneered 20th century viral weapons research. He was one of the founders of **Umbrella Pharmaceuticals**, which developed the T-Virus.

A brilliant and enthusiastic scientist, he held a dark reputation for unethical experiments and mysteriously disappeared in 1988.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but **The Final Chapter** definitely told us that ***James Marcus*** was the only creator so please, what sources do you depend on for your answer?

Answer (score -3):

Here is the official right answer:

Dr. James Marcus worked with Dr. Alexander Isaacs in developing the Progenitor Cell which Marcus used it to cure his daughter, in order to create a better stronger version. Dr. Charles Ashford created the T-Virus from the Progenitor Cell which he used it to cure his daughter also, the T-Virus is the one that causes an uncontrollable mutation not the Progenitor it was derived from.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little what makes this the "official right answer"? That is a bit of a bold statement to be backed solely by your word.

Comment: source please!!

Comment: there is no right answer, the movies tend to not really give a good explanation and they are terrible with continuity, its their fault on that, anything you can used to get the answer, this explanation is from the novelization of The Final Chapter, also you can either choose who is the true creator of the T-Virus, cause knowing the movies not giving a good explanation, saying it was Marcus or Ashford.

Comment: either way there is no official answer, you just gotta credit anyone of them as the true creator of the T-Virus

Comment: If there's no official answer to back what your saying, your basically making it up

Comment: its not made up man, depending on who you think is the true creator of the T-Virus, there is other possible reasons why who is the creator of the T-Virus, i got this info from the novelization of Resident Evil: The Final Chapter and plus the movies continuity are badly written, not my fault bro

Answer (score -4):

Dr James Marcus. If you watch Apocalypse, Dr Ashford use the virus, not created it.

Comment: Welcome to movies&tv.SE. While it is great to distinguish that Dr. Ashford did not create the virus, can you include in your answer who made the T-virus? Also, it would be great if you had a citation. Welcome aboard!

Comment: @John Any sources to back yourself up? anything else to add in your answer?